# Gridview Could not found control for modalpopupextender

Tags: c#, ajax, gridview, modalpopupextender

I have a gridview with column "View" ID= "lnkViewContact". On click of this link signup modalpopupextender will be displayed. This popup is similar for all the rows. But when I am running it the error I am getting is "Could not found control lnkViewContact". How it can be resolved.  one alternative is by using Onclick event on link click but I do not want to do a postback for opening the Popupextender. Below is my code:

```html
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlNoData" runat="server" align="center" Visible="false" Style="height: 300px;
                        width: auto;">
                        <h1 style="font-variant: normal; font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 1.8em;
                            margin-left: 15px; font-weight: lighter; color: Green; margin-top: 100px;">
                            Refine your search.</h1>
                        <h1 style="font-variant: normal; font-family: Times New Roman; font-size: 1.8em;
                            margin-left: 15px; font-weight: lighter; color: Green; margin-left: 100px; margin-right: 100px;">
                            Not finding suitable candidates. </h1>
                        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp3" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlJobPost" BehaviorID="bvJobPost"
                            TargetControlID="lnkPostJobReq" BackgroundCssClass="mBackground" CancelControlID="btnClose">
                        </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPostJobSignUp" Text="Sign Up and Post Job" Font-Size="Medium"
                            runat="server" OnClick="SignUp" Visible="false"></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPostJobReq" Text="Post Job Requirement" Font-Size="Medium"
                            runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:GridView ID="grdSearchResult" runat="server" DataKeyNames="SeekerEmail_Id, Extension"
                        OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="1px"
                        BackColor="White" CellPadding="5" BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="Gray" GridLines="Both"
                        Width="100%">
                        <FooterStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="White"></FooterStyle>
                        <PagerStyle ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="White"></PagerStyle>
                        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" BackColor="Green"></HeaderStyle>
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Job Skills" DataField="Primary_Skill" SortExpression="Primary_Skill"
                                ItemStyle-Width="35%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Wrap="true"
                                ItemStyle-CssClass="grdSearchResultbreakword"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Resume Title" DataField="Resume_Title" SortExpression="Resume_Title"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-Width="30%"
                                ItemStyle-CssClass="grdSearchResultbreakword"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Exp (Years)" DataField="Experience" SortExpression="Experience"
                                ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundField>
                           
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Details Email/Mobile" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-Width="12%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkViewContact" Text="View" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Details Email/Mobile" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                                ItemStyle-Width="15%">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblContact" ForeColor="DarkOrange" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SeekerEmail_Id").ToString() +" / "+ Eval("Contact_Number").ToString()  %>'
                                        Style="word-wrap: normal; word-break: break-all; cursor: default;"></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Download Resume" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDown" Text="Download" runat="server" OnClick="SignUp"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            
                        </Columns>
                        <SelectedRowStyle ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" BackColor="#008A8C"></SelectedRowStyle>
                        <RowStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="White"></RowStyle>
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" BehaviorID="behaviorIDmp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1"
                        TargetControlID="lnkViewContact" CancelControlID="btnCancel" DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" Style="display: none;
                        height: 400px;" DefaultButton="btnRegister">
                        <%--<h1 style="font-variant: normal; font-family: Comic Sans MS; font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: lighter;
                    margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px; text-align: center; color: Blue;">
                    SIGN UP</h1>--%>
                        
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEmailId" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Email address"
                            Style="font-weight: bold; display: block; text-align: left; margin-left: 45px;
                            margin-top: 10px;"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmailAddress" runat="server" class="txtFirstName" MaxLength="100"
                            name="email" TabIndex="3" value="" /><br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator EnableClientScript="true" ID="reqEmailAdress" runat="server"
                            ValidationGroup="modal" ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress" ErrorMessage="Email Address Required"
                            Display="Dynamic" Style="color: Red;" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regEmailAddress" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Not Valid Email ID"
                            ValidationGroup="modal" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtEmailAddress"
                            ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblContactNumber" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Contact Number(Don't prefix 0 or +91)"
                            Style="font-weight: bold; display: block; text-align: left; margin-left: 45px;"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtContactNumber" runat="server" class="txtFirstName" MaxLength="15"
                            name="contact" TabIndex="6" value="" /><br />
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator EnableClientScript="true" ID="reqContactNumber" runat="server"
                            ValidationGroup="modal" ControlToValidate="txtContactNumber" ErrorMessage="Contact Number Required"
                            Display="Dynamic" Style="color: Red;" />
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regContactNumber" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtContactNumber"
                            ValidationGroup="modal" Text="Only 10 digit valid contact number is valid." ValidationExpression="[0-9]{10}"
                            Style="color: Red;" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" ValidationGroup="modal" class="btnempregsubmit" runat="server"
                            Text="Save" OnClick="Register" CausesValidation="false" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="btnClosePopup">Close</asp:HyperLink>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="grdSearchResult" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRegister" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit confusing when you mentioned 'one alternative is by using Onclick event on link click but I do not want to do a postback for opening the Popupextender. ' If you want an OnClick event, you will have to make postback. Below is a suggestion.

.....This part is your code....

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" BehaviorID="behaviorIDmp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1"
                        TargetControlID="lnkViewContact" CancelControlID="btnCancel" DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

....Replace with this......

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" BehaviorID="behaviorIDmp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1"
                        TargetControlID="lnkFake" CancelControlID="btnCancel" DropShadow="true" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

And on the OnClick event code behind, do this to show the pop up

```html
mp1.Show()
```

Comment: Yes your solution works but the problem I am facing with onclick is it is taking too much time to show the popup, maybe because it is refreshing the whole gridview which is carrying lot many rows. And I only want to show a same signup popup for each link of the gridview row. Is there any other way I can display the popup?

Comment: To my knowledge the OnClick event is in the same update panel so it will still be post backed. Sorry I couldn't help on this.

Answer (score 0):

The Linkbutton inside a Gridview cannot be set as a TargetcontrolID of Modalpopupextender because at run time the ID of linkbutton will change dynaically. The work around is use the Onclick event of LinkButton and like in my case if there is any validation in modalpopupextender then validate the controls on server side.